# Using a Struct within a Constructor

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

Using a constructor, can I set values to variables located in the classes private using information that would be stored in a struct vector? This would construct the values for the class, one of which being the string name of the month-monthName-using the numerical place of the month as a guide for the place in the struct vector.

```
//m/d/y;year_is_private_variable
Date(unsigned m, unsigned d, unsigned y){
         year=y;
         for(unsigned i=0;i<12;++i){
             if(m==yVector.mPlace.at(i)){
                 monthName=yVector.mName.at(i);

             }
         }
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean, but could it be that you simply wanted to do `m==yVector.at(i).mPlace` and `monthName=yVector.at(i).mName;` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use values stored by internal parts of class/structure to initialise other class/struct variables at construction time. But, you have to keep in mind that the variables which you want to use shall be initialised before usage.
For purposes of your example you can use *static const* field to store all the months. Simplified code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Date
{
    Date(int month)
        : month_name(values[month])
    {

    }

    std::string month_name;

private:

    static const std::vector<std::string> values;
};

const std::vector<std::string> Date::values = {"may", "april"};

int main()
{
    Date d = Date(1);

    std::cout << d.month_name;

    return 0;
}
```